# Github action not working the same for similar events

Tags: github, automation, github-actions, cicd

I created a github action workflow for automatic labelling of PRs which is behaving rather strangely as it works only when I make a pull request from a different branch, but not with other people contributing to my repo through their forks. The same action throws the error: " Parameter token or opts.auth is required". For reference, these are two different type of contributions to a repo, by self and by other user to my repo:
1)https://github.com/mihirm21/ofep_final/actions/runs/5868948011/job/15912863615?pr=70
2)https://github.com/mihirm21/ofep_final/actions/runs/5868998859/job/15913026155?pr=69

The first one worked fine, as expected but the second one failed.

I tried many things like checking for the github action persmissions, played with some iterations of different kind of PRs which found out the above error, updating permissions of secrets but none could resolve the error.

[A look-out to the github action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ds4p.png)